# Why WPF Databinding is using DataContext from target Element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I often have the following scenario:

I have a custom UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingBindingBindingTest.MyUserControl"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                     mc:Ignorable="d"
                     DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyUserControlValue}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

with its code behind:

```
public partial class MyUserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int MyUserControlValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyUserControlValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyUserControlValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyUserControlValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyUserControlValue", typeof(int), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));     
}
```

This usercontrol I'm using in a other control or window:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingBindingBindingTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:BindingBindingBindingTest">
   <Grid>
      <controls:MyUserControl MyUserControlValue="{Binding MainWindowValue}" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

In its code behind there is a property which should be passed to the usercontrol. This property is initialized in its constructor:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainWindowValue = 34;
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public int MainWindowValue { get; set; }
}
```

Running the application, the usercontrol binding works well.

But the binding defined in the MainWindow.xaml doesnt work. The error messing is following:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'MainWindowValue' property not found on 'object' ''MyUserControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=MainWindowValue; DataItem='MyUserControl' (Name=''); target element is 'MyUserControl' (Name=''); target property is 'MyUserControlValue' (type 'Int32')
```

As described in the error message, the property MainWindowValue is not fount on MyUserControl.

And here is my question: Why the property is expected on MyUserControl? In my opinion, the binding is made to the MainWindowValue of the MainWindow because the DataContext is set to its own instance (DataContext = this).

Of course it's simple to fix this issue by defining the source of the binding. But I'm interesting about the reason of this behavior.

Any idea about this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any difference in your 2 XAML examples other than you map the namespace to bindingBindingBindingTest in one and to controls in the other. If the binding is working in one it should be working in the other. Did you copy the wrong code into your question?

Comment: @LeeO.: sorry mi fault. yes I pasted wrong code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is expected on `MyUserControl` because `MyUserControl.xaml` contains the following:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

This points the `DataContext` of the `MyUserControl` instance back to itself.  This happens as part of the call to the `MyUserControl()` constructor, which happens *before* the `MyUserControlValue` setter is evaluated in `MainWindow`:

```
<controls:MyUserControl MyUserControlValue="{Binding MainWindowValue}" />
```

By the time this setter is evaluated, the `DataContext` of the `MyUserControl` has been set to itself.  When the binding engine looks for the `MainWindowValue` property, it looks on the `MyUserControl`, because that's the data context.  The binding evaluates against the data context of the target object, **not** the data context of the "parent" object.

A simple workaround would be to give the window a name, and use `ElementName` to make the binding use the window as its binding root:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingBindingBindingTest.MainWindow"
        x:Name="Root"
        ...>
   <Grid>
      <controls:MyUserControl
          MyUserControlValue="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=MainWindowValue}" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Also, as a matter of style, I would recommend against initializing control properties in both the constructor *and* the Xaml.  When possible, you should stick to initializing values in one place (preferably the Xaml).  If you want to specify a default value, then specify it in the `DependencyProperty` metadata when you `Register()` the property.  If the value you're specifying is specific to the control *instance*, then set the value where you *declare* the instance.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation. I really didn't realize that the binding evaluates the data context of the target object. What I still do not understand is, how are standard controles (e.g. TextBox, TextBlock etc.) solve this problem. Because there the binding I described in the MainWindow works perfectly.

Comment: Standard WPF controls are a bit different from a `UserControl`; they are *templated controls*.  A style (by default, the system style) is applied to each control in the visual tree, and the style specifies an appearance in the form of a *template*.  The template typically binds to properties on the templated control using `RelativeSource.TemplatedParent`, as opposed to binding against the data context.  Standard controls do not use the `DataContext` to communicate between the control 'template' and the control 'model' at all.